# Split xts into intervals separated by zeros?

Tags: r, xts

Let's assume I have numeric xts with next values:

```
111 00 111 -1-1-1 000 11
```

How can I extract intervals between zeros, so the output is another three xts objects with proper index:

xts1 : `111`

xts2 : `111-1-1-1`

xts3 : `11`

Comment: Please share a sample of your actual `xts` object.

Comment: Are those character? Numbers? Reproducible example would be really helpful?

Comment: the values are numeric.

Answer (score 2):

You could do this. First we remove the spaces with `gsub`. Finally, we split the elements of the character vector using the character 0 followed by the metacharacter + so if matches if 0 occurs one or more times.

```
x <- c("111 00 111 -1-1-1 000 11")
x <- gsub(" ", "", x , fixed = TRUE)
x <- unlist(strsplit(x, split="0+"))
x
```

Output:

```
[1] "111"       "111-1-1-1" "11"
```